# Unable to install Google play services on VS Android Emulator (Marshmallow 6.0)

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I am trying to install google play services on a Marshmallow device listed below. I tried both, drag and drop and copy SD card methods. I get below errors. I tried some other zip files as well with no luck. Are there any setup files that work? or anything that I am missing? Note this works fine for Kitkat.

Google play app downloaded from:
http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/
ARM Devices: open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip – (Mirror #1) – Latest!
This is the one you need to install. ARM is the most popular 32-bit platform for Android devices.

http://www.devfiles.co/download/U4VcvptL/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip

Device configuration:

[image]

[image]

Errors after install:

```
Installing flashable ZIP file '/sdcard/download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip'
Unpacking archive '/sdcard/download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip' to '/data/local/tmp/.flash_tmp'
 extracting: Core/configupdater-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/defaultetc-common.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/defaultframework-common.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/gmscore-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/googlebackuptransport-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/googlecontactssync-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/googlefeedback-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/googleonetimeinitializer-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/googlepartnersetup-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/gsfcore-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/gsflogin-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/setupwizarddefault-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/setupwizardtablet-all.tar.xz
 extracting: Core/vending-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/calculatorgoogle-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/calendargoogle-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/calsync-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/clockgoogle-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/dialerframework-common.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/exchangegoogle-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/facedetect-lib-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/faceunlock-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/faceunlock-common.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/faceunlock-lib-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/gmail-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/googlenow-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/googletts-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/hangouts-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/maps-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/packageinstallergoogle-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/photos-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/search-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/speech-common.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/taggoogle-all.tar.xz
 extracting: GApps/youtube-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: LICENSE
 extracting: META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary
 extracting: META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
 extracting: Optional/swypelibs-lib-arm.tar.xz
 extracting: app_densities.txt
 extracting: app_sizes.txt
 extracting: bkup_tail.sh
 extracting: busybox-arm
 extracting: g.prop
 extracting: gapps-remove.txt
 extracting: installer.sh
 extracting: xzdec-arm
 extracting: zip-arm
 extracting: META-INF/com/android/otacert
 extracting: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 extracting: META-INF/CERT.SF
 extracting: META-INF/CERT.RSA
Installing file '/system/*'
cp: /data/local/tmp/.flash_tmp/system/*: No such file or directory
cp: bad '/data/local/tmp/.flash_tmp/system/*': No such file or directory
Could not copy '/data/local/tmp/.flash_tmp/system/*' to '/system/*'
```

Comment: As a workaround, I did install Genymotion (uninstall Hyper-V first), and then install google play services download from http://opengapps.org

Comment: Isn't emulator x86? But you tried to install ARM version

Answer (score 2):

I have tried everything, the following is the best -
http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2016/04/installing-gapps-in-visual-studio.html